# An Application User is not Created when I run the program?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

i want to create a new role for admin . i am using .net framework mvc 5 but when i run the application it does not create the user and does not save it in the database although the role with id is created successfully and i can see it through the database.

my code is written in startup.cs

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
            CreateUserAndRoles();
        }

        public void CreateUserAndRoles()
        {
            ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

            if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
            {
                var role = new IdentityRole("Admin");
                roleManager.Create(role);

                var user = new ApplicationUser();
                user.UserName = "admin";
                user.Email = "admin@admin.com";
                string password = "12345";

                var newuser = userManager.Create(user, password);
                if (newuser.Succeeded)
                {
                    userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've never used these features before, but... Generally when using something with a name like `DbContext`, if you make changes in the program, you need to tell the context that the changes should be saved.

Comment: Isn’t this what a Seed method in EF is supposed to be used for?